# For a given string check if matches the pattern [scala]

Tags: regex, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am beginner in Scala and I was wondering how I can build a function to check if it matches a definite pattern or not?

For example:

```
def patternFound(s:String): Boolean = (s) match {
    case s matches xyxy pattern => true //where x,y are two consecutive characters in the string
    case s matches xxyy pattern => false //where x, y are two characters in that string
    case (_) => false //default
}
//Here x,y are not definite characters but the string s should match a pattern 
//which consist a string of pattern containing characters in alternating positions

patternFound("babab")//true because pattern of xyxy found in it
patternFound("baabba")//false because pattern of xxyy found in it
```

**Can anyone show with an example how I can achieve this?**

Looking for a solution which returns true for any occurrence of xyxyxy pattern in a string, but returns false when the pattern is xxyy in that string.

> Example: The function should return true if the string is "babab" or
>   "ababa" (which has pattern xyxy in it), but returns false for "aabba"
>   or "bbaab" (which has the pattern xxyy in it)

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two examples you've posted, these two Regex patterns will cover it.

```
def patternFound(s:String): Boolean = {
  val ptrn1 = "(.)(.)\\1\\2".r
  val ptrn2 = "(.)\\1(.)\\2".r
  s match {
    case ptrn1(_,_) => true
    case ptrn2(_,_) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

proof:

```
patternFound("rrgg")  // res0: Boolean = true
patternFound("hqhq")  // res1: Boolean = true
patternFound("cccx")  // res2: Boolean = false
```

But I suspect that your requirements, as stated, are not specific enough to cover exactly what you're looking for.

---

**UPDATE**

You're 2nd requirement now makes no sense. *Everything* that doesn't match the 1st pattern will return `false` so there's no point in testing for a specific pattern to return `false`.

```
def patternFound(s:String): Boolean = {
  val ptrn = "(.)(.)\\1\\2".r.unanchored
  s match {
    case ptrn(_,_) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
patternFound("babab")   //true because pattern of xyxy found in it
patternFound("baabba")  //false because it doesn't match the target pattern
```

Comment: honestly,I am amazed! this is really powerful and amazing. But what I am trying to achieve is to write a function which will return true for a string "babab" because it contains the pattern xyxy (substring of "babab" is baba which matches the repetitive pattern). And the same function should return false if the string passed is "aabba" because it has the pattern xxyy in it (substring of "aabba" is "aabb" which matches xxyy => false)

Comment: @MoodyCody; please clarify. Your question states `matches "xxyy" => true` but now you say "matches xxyy => false".

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. The wording might have been misleading a little bit. I have also included example in the question to clarify the requirement.

Comment: amazing! works like charm! if you don't mind can I ask which book/reference material I should follow to learn scala (so that i can also create pattern matching the way you did) better?

Comment: Well this question is more about Regular Expressions than it is about Scala. Those are two separate things. You might spend some time with [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) but I'm sure there are many good RE tutorials available online.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct.
You need to remove "s matches" from the body of the function, it is already in the method definition line "(s) match".

See also https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am aware of that. That's why I am looking for what I can do to match a certain pattern. In my example x,y are undefined characters.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible with regular expressions and look arounds, but I just created a helper function:

```
/**
  * Checks for recurring pattern in a String
  * @param s The input String to check
  * @param patternSize The size of the expected pattern.  For example in the String "aabbaabbaabb" the pattern is "aabb" which is a length of 4
  */
def checkPattern(s: String, patternSize: Int): Boolean = {
  val grouped = s.grouped(patternSize)
  grouped.toSet.size == 1 // everything should be the same
}
```

Some example usage of that function:

```
checkPattern("abababab", 2) // true
checkPattern("aabbaabbaabb", 2) // false
checkPattern("aabbaabbaabb", 4) // true
checkPattern("abcabcabc", 3) // true
```

So for your code you could do use it with some guard statements:

```
def patternFound(s: String): Boolean = s match {
  case "" => false // empty Strings can't have patterns
  case s if checkPattern(s, 2) => true
  case s if checkPattern(s, 4) => true
  case _ => false
}

patternFound("ababababab") // true
patternFound("aabbaabb") // true
patternFound("aabbzz") // false
```

---

Edit: I think the other answer is better for what you are looking for, but here is my updated answer for you updated question:

```
def patternFound(s: String): Boolean = s match {
  s.nonEmpty && checkPattern(s, 2)
}
```

Comment: hi @Tyler I really appreciate the solution but it is not quite what I am looking for, although it does suffice the question I asked. And I would definitely upvote your solution once I have the adequate reps to do so. 
But I am actually looking to create a solution which returns true for pattern of xyxyxy.... or yxyxyx... but false for xxyy.... or yyxx.... Any idea how I may be achieve that effectively?

Comment: Looks like you updated your question.  Ill update my answer.